# Save curl response AND -w to variables

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using the following command to curl an url, and showing the `response_code` and `time_total` provided by the [`--write-out`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) option

```sh
curl -o /dev/null -sL $@ -w "$(printf %-100.100s $@) %{response_code}\t%{time_total}\n"
# https://example.com/?p=5                                200            0.084437
```

Since some pages show a **cms based 404**, I would like to check the page content for a particular string, and showing a `contains: true/false` in the output:

```
https://example.com/?p=4                  No               200           0.084437
https://example.com/?p=5                  Yes              200           0.081241
```

---

So I guess **the real question is**, how do I get both the `-w` to show his output, while saving the response body to a variable?

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572424/retrieve-both-http-status-code-and-content-from-curl-in-a-shell-script) answer, I'm currently using this workaround:

```sh
# <body>\n<code>#<time>
c=$(curl -o - -s -L ${1} -w "%{response_code}#%{time_total}")

# Body
cb=$(sed '$ d' <<< "$c")

# Info
ci=$(tail -n1 <<< "$c")
IFS='#' read -r -a cs <<< "$ci"

# CMS-404
ul=<regex magic>
[[ $ul != ${2} ]] && pe="CMS-404" || pe=""

# Print result
printf "$(printf %-100.100s ${1})\t${pe}\t\t${cs[0]}\t${cs[1]}\n"
```

It's captures the complete output, get's the **last** line, witch contains the `-w` information, and using `sed` to get the remaining content, the body.

Since I would like the `-w` output to (optionally) be multiple lines, I'm looking for a more reliably way to do this.

---

Linked question/answers

- [How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl)

  Since [`-w`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) can't output the page contents, not an option
- [How to store curl output in multiple variables in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60816352/how-to-store-curl-output-in-multiple-variables-in-bash)

  Is to split the page content, no `-w` options
- [Curl to return http status code along with the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906626/curl-to-return-http-status-code-along-with-the-response)

  Doesn't save to variable

Additional information

|  | Version |
| --- | --- |
| curl | 7.64.1 |
| bash | 3.2.57(1)-release |
| OS | Mac OS X 10.15.7 |

---

Edit, based on [@Philippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399300/5625547), this seems to work, however, the `ci="${c#*$'\1'}"` is extreme slow, since I'm using this function for 1000+ url's, I'm hoping for a 'faster' solution.

I've tested this with the below script, simplified;

```
#!/bin/bash

get() {

    echo "---> ${1}"

    # Request
    c=$(curl -o - -s -L ${1} -w $'\1'"%{response_code}#%{time_total}")

    # Body
    cb="${c%$'\1'*}"
    time_after_body=$(date +%s%N)

    ci="${c#*$'\1'}"
    time_after_info=$(date +%s%N)

    time_diff="$((time_after_info - time_after_body))"
    echo "TimeDiff: ${time_diff}ms"
    echo "CurlInfo: ${ci}"
}

get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395089/save-curl-response-and-w-to-variables"
```

```
 ✗ ./small_so.sh
---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395089/save-curl-response-and-w-to-variables
TimeDiff: 9886412000ms
CurlInfo: 200#0.469687
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a marker like `$'\1'` ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
c=$(curl -o - -s -L ${1} -w $'\1'"%{response_code}#%{time_total}")

cb="${c%$'\1'*}"

ci="${c#*$'\1'}"

declare -p cb ci

# Calling method : ./test.sh "https://example.com/?p=5"
```

I have just tested on macos :

```
~/$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

~/$ /bin/bash test.sh "https://example.com/?p=5"
declare -- cb="<!doctype html>
...
"
declare -- ci="200#0.693779"
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code hangs on `ci="${c#*$'\1'}"`, never used those markers before. Are there any bash version limitations? Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: Updated my answer.  `bash 3.2.57` should support the syntax in my script. Can you share command you use ?

Comment: If updated my question. Got it working with your example. Seems like a solid solution, many thanks. However, could you please take a look at the example script in the OP, I'm the `ci="${c#*$'\1'}"` seems to take quite some time.

Comment: Indeed, it's quite slow on my side as well (18 seconds). Can you try `ci="${c##*$'\1'}"` with double `#`

Comment: Wouw, thats quite some difference haha. About 0.8 seconds for a single request. Do you mind explaining why this has such a huge impact?

Comment: ##*$'\1' removes longest string until $'\1' whereas `#*$'\1'` removes shortest. They should be equivalent in this case, so I don't know either why there is this huge impact.